# How to make AngularJS smart table header with the up/down arrows initially to promote users

Tags: angularjs, smart-table, tableheader

In jQuery, this is database plug-in to sort table nicely. In AngularJS, I found smart-table is very similar, and also meet most of my needs.
However, I have one more request, which is to have those UP/DOWN arrows initially to promote users those columns are sortable.

I got how to have to arrow when the column is sorted, BUT I don't know how to have both up/down arrows before sorting and change to up or down arrow when the column is sorted.

```
 <thead>
        <tr class="sortable">
            <th >Toggle Expand/Collapse</th>
            <th st-sort="projectName" st-sort-default="default" st-skip-natural="true">Project Name</th>
            <th st-sort="val" st-skip-natural="true">Project Value</th>
            <th st-sort="cost">Cost of Project</th>
            <th st-sort="cost_benefit_ratio">Cost Benefit Ratio</th>
            <th st-sort="creatorName">Creator</th>
            <th st-sort="create_at">Create Time</th>
            <th st-sort="LastEditorName">Last Editor</th>
            <th st-sort="edit_at">Edit Time</th>
            <th> Edit </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="10"><input st-search="" class="form-control" placeholder="global search ..." type="text"/></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Please see my attached picture.

The first one is what I want to achieve. The second one is my current situation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Please post a [mcve] - we will help you solve problems, but don't ask us to write code for you.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add my code. @penne12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved my problem.

In the CSS:

```
table thead tr.sortable th{
    background-image:url("./images/up-down-arrow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
}

.sortable {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.st-sort-ascent{
    background-image:url("./images/up-arrow.png") !important;

}

.st-sort-descent{
    background-image:url("./images/down-arrow.png") !important;
}
```

Make sure "!important" is added, so the background image will be override.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem except I wanted the sort toggle arrows to be on the right of the headers.

I overrode the .st-sort-ascent:before CSS rules that smart table applies with my own empty ones, and applied an :after rule.

Not all my columns are sortable, so I only applied the "sort-header" class to the ones that were.

I made use of the FontAwesome icons instead of images.

```
.sort-header {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.sort-header:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '  \f0dc';
    color: lightgrey;
}
.st-sort-ascent:before {
    content: '';
}
.st-sort-ascent:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '  \f0de';
    color: black;
}
.st-sort-descent:before {
    content: '';
}
.st-sort-descent:after{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '  \f0dd';
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would do that with filters. You can add a filter in your ng-repeat and that should almost automatically sort and filter the results.

orderBy is described here

[angular orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```css
.st-table thead tr th {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 18px;
  position: relative;
}
.st-table thead tr th:before,
.st-table thead tr th:after{
  content: "";
  border-width: 0 4px 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000 transparent;
  visibility: visible;
  right: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .3;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
.st-table thead tr th:before{
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #000;
}
.st-table thead tr th.st-sort-ascent:before{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.st-table thead tr th.st-sort-ascent:after{
  visibility: visible;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  -khtml-opacity: .6;
  -moz-opacity: .6;
  opacity: .6;
}
.st-table thead tr th.st-sort-descent:before{
  visibility: visible;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  -khtml-opacity: .6;
  -moz-opacity: .6;
  opacity: .6;
}
.st-table thead tr th.st-sort-descent:after{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```